# Coping latest excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy excel sheet from the latest file. I am getting runtime error 402 object required. Please help.

```
Sub NewestFile()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    
    MyPath = "C:\glad\"
    If (MyPath) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `.Copy.Copy` really in your code? I guess that should be only one `Copy`...

Comment: The "Object Required" error means you tried to access the members of something that doesn't have members. `.Copy.Copy` is the issue.

Comment: Btw: Doesn't look like the code is specific for a Mac. I assume you wanted to tag the question with "Macros" - but that's also invalid (the tag clearly states that it is not for VBA macros)

Comment: Sorry guys i am really new to this. Below code works for me to copy      
 worksheet.Sub CopyWB()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\example.xlsx")
closedBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: i am trying to update the code by looking for the most updated excel file than naming a file

Comment: @FaneDuru `FileDateTime` is a build-in VBA command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filedatetime-function

Comment: @FunThomas Ups... I never used it and I did not even know about its existence. Thanks! I will delete my comment.

Comment: @newbee: Have you now removed the superfluous `.Copy`? Is it working now? Any other error?